# unable to fetch the selected option from mat-form-field to generate the url dynamically in angular2

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have created sample application in angular2 where when a admin logs into the application and selects the required institute from the dropdown in the AdminComponent and navigates into the application.

Here I want to generate the URL dynamically which includes the selected institute.

Please access my sample application [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/role-based-authentication-xnspcv?file=app%2Fadmin%2Fadmin.component.ts)

In my current scenario when the admin logs in and selects the required institute and navigates into the application ,the URL is of kind.......

```
**http://localhost:4200/application/home**
```

But I want this URL to be generated dynamically with selected institute name in the URL.

For Example : If the selected institute is **Arizona-ARP** , the URL when navigating to home page look like ....

```
**http://localhost:4200/Arizona/application/home**
```

can anybody please help me to build my sample application as required ...?

Comment: Why you want to change the URL particularly?

Comment: In my admin page I have form field where i need to select an option i.e Institute and navigate to home page.. When I select a particular institute then I need to display that selected institute in the URL

Comment: My question is why you need to display the selected institute in **URL**?

Comment: as i can select any option depending on the requirement so i need that selected institution to be appended between the URL

Comment: I have assigned that task to be done...:-(

Comment: Actually the URl works under by the Route configuration section. If the dynamic URL is didn't defined in config section, then how the application could run?  If you change the URL dynamically then you should hard coded that URL in route config section.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177786/discussion-between-heena-and-ramesh-rajendran).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kindly check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/role-based-authentication-hkknjb?file=app/admin/admin.component.html)  for working code

---

@Chuchu has partially done. But additionally you need define you dynamic URL's in route config. like below

```
  {path:'Admin/Apollo/application/home',component: HomeComponent},
                           {path:'Admin/Arizona/application/home',component: HomeComponent},
                           {path:'Admin/Adventing/application/home',component: HomeComponent},
                           {path:'Admin/Trustling/application/home',component: HomeComponent},
                           {path:'application/home',component: HomeComponent},
```

Comment: Yes, i just saw the routing.module and the module needs that lines.

Answer (score 1):

check this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/role-based-authentication-5bfzmy

I edit your code, in template

```
<mat-form-field floatPlaceholder="never">
    <mat-select style="min-width: 200px;" placeholder=" Institution " [(ngModel)]="institute" name="institute">

    <mat-option *ngFor="let ins of options" [value]="ins.InstituteName" >
                {{ ins.InstituteName}}-{{ ins.typ}}
    </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

...

```
routerLink='{{institute}}/application/home'
```

in button

In ts

```
institute: string;
options: any;
this.options = data;
```

In the example at stackblitz when you change select the link button change, but there is a console error when you click button.

Comment: But I am unable to see the dynamic URL as I needed after selecting the institute... And Iam getting the following error in my console...  Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'Admin/Apollo/application/home'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'Admin/Apollo/application/home'
    at